# Apache Rewrite if file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If `offline.html` exists in the root directory, rewrite to it.

I created the following .htaccess file and placed it in the root directory:

```
RewriteCond offline.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /offline.html [L]
```

For some reason this doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: You test `html` but you rewrite `php`???

Comment: @Croises yes, a typo, but that still doesn't make it work. I'm almost sure the issue is in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition will always fail:

```
RewriteCond offline.html -f
```

because `-f` needs full path of the file you are checking.

You can use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` (Apache internal variable pointing to your website root) before filename you're checking to make a full path:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/offline.html -f
RewriteRule ^ offline.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/offline.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /offline.html [L]
```